# Iterating over BlockNode in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to do some validation of templates needed in my Django app.
For this I need to iterate over nodes of a template.
Somehow [BlockNode](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/loader_tags.py#L45) nodes are not part of the nodelist.
Is there a way to include them.

```
from django.template import Template
template = Template(
    '''{% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block content %}
    Click the next button...
    {% endblock %}''')
print template.nodelist
```

Answer (score 0):

Templates are more like a map than a list. Each node returned from that initial call to `template.nodelist` can in turn have nodes with `nodelists` so, a recursive descent would be needed to actually enumerate all the values.

Here's a sample of my quick attempt plus a little lambda handling to help you find what you are looking for.

```
def node_descender(node_list, l=None):
    for child_node in node_list:
        print(child_node)
        if l and l(child_node):
            print("Got here!")
        if hasattr(child_node, 'nodelist'):
            node_descender(child_node.nodelist)

node_descender(template.nodelist, lambda x: isinstance(x, BlockNode) and x.name == "subject")
```